# How to use pkcs11 modules in firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions, pkcs#11

There is the "Security Devices" button in Firefox 51 (Preferenced/Advanced/Certificates), that opens Device Manager, where we can load PKCS11 modules.
The question is how to work with them:

1. Can I access them from a page script?
2. or only from WebExtensions? I saw in [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/PKCS11/Module_Installation): * Extensions can programmatically manage PKCS11 modules using the nsIPKCS11 programming interface*. Can they do something more?
3. or there must be some kind of server-side support to make browser work with USB crypto token device (for example) using pkcs11 module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No, you can't. It was possible before Firefox 3.5.
2. nsIPKCS11 programming interface is not exposed to WebExtensions. It was exposed to legacy addons which stopped working in Firefox 57. The closest API you get is the WebExtensions API pkcs11: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/pkcs11 (available since Firefox 58)
3. No idea, I'm sorry.